# RavenDB: Search with whitespace, behaving like String.Contains

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

**TL;DR** how to run exact equivalent of `.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(value))` query in RavenDB, even when `value` string contains spaces (whitecharacters)?

---

We're querying RavenDB with LINQ. We want to query with `String.Contains`-like constraint. As the RavenDb prevents `.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(value))` queries, we're using `LinqExtensions.Search` extension method, following the examples in the documentation: 

`query = query.Search(t => t.Name, $"*{value}*",
                    escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowAllWildcards,
                    options: SearchOptions.And);`

Unfortunately this doesn't work as expected when the search term contains the space character, most likely because of this: https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/f3b5f3a186d07776bf38bf9effab4d7d75d5c647/Raven.Client.Lightweight/Document/AbstractDocumentQuery.cs#L1759

We've been trying manual space escaping, with no success so far:

`var value = RavenQuery.Escape(filter.NameContains).Replace(" ", @"\ ");

query = query.Search(t => t.Name, $"*{value}*",
                    escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.AllowAllWildcards,
                    options: SearchOptions.And);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `Index` option of the field to `Analyzed`

```
public class YourObject_ByName : AbstractIndexCreationTask<YourObject>
{
    public YourObject_ByName()
    {
        Map = objs => objs .Select(x => new { x.Name });

        Indexes.Add(x => x.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

And then you can query using `DocumentQuery`:

```
session.Advanced.DocumentQuery<YourObject, YourObject_ByName>()
    .Where("(Name: *term*)")
    .ToList();
```